# How to dump all the functions and procedures(not include tables) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two procedures in my [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) database called **test_proc1** and **test_proc2**.I want to export the code of these two procedures,but I found the exported file contains nothing and I don't know why.Below is the detailed description of my question:

1.Code of the procedure **test_proc1**:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `testmanagementb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc1`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_proc1`()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM system_users;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

2.Code of the procedure **test_proc2**:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `testmanagementb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc2`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test_proc2`()
BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM testcase_node;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

3.The command used to export the procedures(the database name is *testmanagementb*):

`mysqldump -u root -p -ntdR testmanagementb > procs.sql`

4.The exported result is listed below:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: testmanagementb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.0.51b-community-nt

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'testmanagementb'
--
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc1` */;;
/*!50003 SET SESSION SQL_MODE=""*/;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50020 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 PROCEDURE `test_proc1`()
BEGIN
    select * from system_users;
    END */;;
/*!50003 SET SESSION SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE*/;;
/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc2` */;;
/*!50003 SET SESSION SQL_MODE=""*/;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50020 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 PROCEDURE `test_proc2`()
BEGIN
      select * from testcase_node;
    END */;;
/*!50003 SET SESSION SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE*/;;
DELIMITER ;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2014-02-24  6:03:25
```

My question is:***Why the exported file in step 4 contains nothing?Is there something wrong in my export command?***

Comment: You file contains `Stored procedure` What is the issue ?

Comment: @AbdulManaf ,yes it contains `Stored procedure`,but as you can see all the procedures are annotated,so the export file is useless,that's my question!

Answer (score 1):

You can take dump using `mysqldump` without  table structure / data and other options, below is the syntax

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db world_copy > outputfile.sql
```

Comment: I just finished my question,could you read it and give me some advices,please?Thanks in advance!